# Converting part of rows of dataframe from numbers to datetime, but got weird numbers

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

**I'm trying to convert some rows of dataframe from numbers to datetime, but got weird numbers.**

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [dt.datetime(2018,1,1), 1.2, 3.2, 2.1]})
mask = df['col'].apply(lambda x:type(x)==float) # find rows that are numbers
# convert numbers to datetime
df.loc[mask, 'col'] = df.loc[mask, 'col'].apply(
    lambda x: dt.datetime(2018,5,1) + dt.timedelta(days=(x*365)))
print(df) 

col
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00
1  1562976000000000000
2  1626048000000000000
3  1591358400000000000
```

Why got huge numbers in rows 1~3? I guess the reason is that type of elements in different rows are different. But I really want to do the change within the data frame. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you have a column of mixed dtypes (datetimes and floats). Pandas, being confused, assumes that the values you're assigning are *also* floats, and attempts to convert the datetimes in index 1 through 3 to numbers (what you see is the number of nanoseconds since the epoch in 1970).

Here's a vectorised fix using `pd.to_numeric`, `pd.to_timedelta`, and `pd.to_datetime`:

```
((pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_numeric(df.col, errors='coerce')) * 365 
    + pd.to_datetime('2018-05-01')).fillna(df.col)
)

0   2018-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
1   2018-05-01 00:00:00.000000365
2   2018-05-01 00:00:00.000001095
3   2018-05-01 00:00:00.000000730
Name: col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I see! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly familiar with pandas, but it looks like the datetime series you are creating in `df.loc[mask, 'col'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime(2018,5,1) + dt.timedelta(days=(x*365)))` is getting implicitly cast to an integer data type when it is assigned into `df.loc[mask, 'col']`. I'm not sure why Pandas would do this, but that seems to be what's causing your problem. Here is a quick solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [dt.datetime(2018, 1, 1), 1.2, 3.2, 2.1]})

df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime(2018, 5, 1) + dt.timedelta(days=(x * 365)) if type(x) == float else x)
```

What
I
find
confusing is why
Pandas
converts
some of the elements of the
series (elements at index 1-3)
to
integers, while leaving other elements (element at index 0) as is. In
other
words, why
convert
the
elements
of
the
series
that
are
being
assigned *into* the
series(`df.loc[mask, 'col'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime(2018, 5, 1) + dt.timedelta(days=(x * 365))`)
from a data
type
of
datetimes
to
integers,
while not converting the element that already exists in the series from datetime to integer? Seems unintuitive to me, but maybe I'm missing something. @coldspeed, can you clarify?

Comment: Thank you for answer, Chris! Your solution should work for me. But I'm still curious why my old method didn't work. The outputs are just large integers. They are not even timestamp. I tried to use datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp() to convert the integers to datetime, but it didn't work.